# How to add color to some words in a text in html?

Tags: html

For example, I want to add color=red to the phone and email, enclosed by **...**. It seems I can't use an embedded  to add color. If I don't use CSS, how can I directly add color to it?

```
<p>For appointment, please call Martin at <strong>xxx-xxx-xxxx</strong> or email at <strong>support@test.com.</strong></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use inline-styling for this purpose

```html
<p>For appointment, please call Martin at <strong style="color:red">xxx-xxx-xxxx</strong> or email at <strong style="color:red">support@test.com.</strong></p>
```

If you want you can add additional styling properties in style attribute of HTML Element by separating properties with `;`

Comment: inline-style is also css... (which OP said he can't use)

Comment: Then how exactly would you add color to an HTML element? @tacoshy

Comment: if you cant use CSS then either with JS or by adding obsolete HTML4 tags such as `<font>`

Comment: inline style is fine, as long as i don't use another css file

Comment: Then your question is missing information, because one could easily interpret it as requiring it to not have CSS at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't "want" to use css, "font" seems to have a color property...

```
<p>For appointment, please call Martin at <strong><font color="red">xxx-xxx-xxxx</font></strong> or email at <strong><font color="blue">support@test.com</font></strong>.</p>
```

Tell us why you don't want to use css?

Comment: it's a simple html page.

Comment: FYI, you can have styles in a seperate file, in the page, or inline on the html element. It's all still CSS. Maybe clarify your question to state that you don't want to use extra css files to style your html.

Comment: The `<font>` element has been [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete) for 15 years or more. The `color` attribute for 20.

Comment: True, but heck, my browser(s) still render it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `<style>` element to use CSS without referencing another CSS file.

```html
<style>
  .redtext {
    color: red;
  }
</style>
<p>For appointment, please call Martin at <strong class="redtext">xxx-xxx-xxxx</strong> or email at <strong class="redtext">support@test.com.</strong></p>
```